# MkDocs - How to include directory names in automatic generation of nav

Tags: markdown, documentation, mkdocs

I am trying to use mkdocs to auto-generate navigation. nav is auto-generated in alphanumeric order of filenames. However, it does not work well when there are directories in it. Is there a better way?

file tree

```
docs/
├── 1.md
├── 2.md
├── 3/
│   └── ...
└── 4.md
```

Results

```
1
2
4
3
```

Desired results

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin [Include-dir-to-nav](https://pypi.org/project/mkdocs-include-dir-to-nav/)

There specify just configure:

```yaml
plugins:
  - search
  - include_dir_to_nav:
    sort_file: true
    sort_directory: true
```